# handle lifetime of returned references to returned owner

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to have a function which owns its parameter, and returns ownership along with references to that parameter - but I can't figure out how to annotate the lifetime for rust to allow it:

```
fn line_refs(s: String) -> (String, Vec<&str>) {
  (s, s.lines().collect())
}
```

Rust requires I add lifetime to the refs, but I'm not sure how I indicate that their lifetime is associated with s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct), tuples are just `struct`s without a name.

Comment: Moving `s` back to the caller invalidates all of the references, which is why you cannot do this in this way. Note that this kind of code _would_ compile under C++, but then would cause undefined behavior during runtime. Rust is protecting you.

Comment: @cdhowie I get that the address of s changes and thus references to s are invalidated. But a String is actually a smart pointer, and the data it points to is still at the same address, so it should still be valid after the move - how can I keep references to that underlying data?

Comment: @feature_engineer You can't without using unsafe code. See the linked duplicate. (Note also that nothing precludes a "small string optimization" in `String`'s implementation, and then what you ask would be _very_ problematic, because the returned references very well could point into `s`.)